# Iterate over an array n items at a time and continue the iteration

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

I'm trying to build a CLI. I want to print the name of each object stored in my array. This is how my array looks like:

```
my_arr = [#<MyObject::Obj:0x007f828daf33b0>, #<MyObject::Obj:0x007f358daf33b0>..]
```

Instead of showing a long list at once, I want the user to take action to display 200/1000 names at a time. This is my code:

```
my_arr.each_with_index do |my_obj, index|
  puts "#{index} #{my_obj.name}"
end
```

I'm thinking to use `case` statement to build the user interaction part, but having issues finding ways to split my Array. How can I start iterating on my Array, break out from the iteration (ask for user input) and after that continue to iterate where I left off?

Comment: Updated, hopefully it should be more clear now.

Comment: Did any of the answers help?

Comment: I will take a look later tonight, thanks for all the suggestions so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has an [`Enumerable#each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) method that will give you an array in groups, which could allow you to do something similar to:

```
my_arr = my_arr.collect.with_index do |my_obj, index|
  "#{index} #{my_obj.name}" # do this all the way up here to get the original index
end.each_slice(5)

length = my_arr.size - 1 # how many groups do we need to display
my_arr.each.with_index do |group, index|
  puts group.join("\n") # show the group, which is already in the desired format

  if index < length # if there are more groups to show,
                    # show a message and wait for input
    puts "-- MORE --"
    gets
  end
end
```

Comment: No need for the initial intermediary `Array`. something like this would work equivalently well `my_arr.each_with_index.each_slice(5) {|slice| puts slice.map {|e,i| "#{i} #{e}"}; gets}` where `5` is the number of elements to show on each enter press

Comment: I ended up using this solution and it worked. I ended up slicing my Array which I iterated over to print. I used this in combination with `next` and `break` to stop or continue my loop. Thanks for all the answers and I will try the other solutions if I have time during the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break` and `next`. A short demo -

```
def foo_next(arr)
  arr.each_with_index { |item, index| 
    next if index % 2 == 0
    puts item
  }
end


def foo_break(arr)
  arr.each_with_index { |item, index| 
    puts item
    break if index % 2 == 0
  }
end

nums = (1..10).to_a

foo_next(nums) # prints 2 4 6 8 10

foo_break(nums) # prints 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an [enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator.html) to enable a stop/continue process:

```
arr = ('a'..'j').to_a
 #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
enum = arr.to_enum

def taker n, enum
  n.times.with_object [] { |_, o| o << enum.next }
end
```

Then take how ever many elements you want...

```
taker 2, enum
 #=> ["a", "b"]
```

...and pick up from where you left off:

```
taker 3, enum
 #=> ["c", "d", "e"]
taker 1, enum
 #=> ["f"]
```

How you print the output and/or user-prompt is up to you.